# Multisession (future) and fable

Tags: r, cross-validation, fable-r, r-future

I'm trying to use the `ARIMA` function from the `fable` package. I'd like to test, using cross validation, every specification, given by the `pdqPDQ` data.frame rows, using a multisession plan from the `future` package. I will then make forecasts and later calculate accuracy measures.

`ARIMA` function cannot see the `pdqPDQ` object. I'm aware of the future [missing globals](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html) issues, and maybe that's the case here (?).

Any ideas for how I could solve this?

```
library(GetBCBData)
library(lubridate)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(tidyr)
library(future)
library(dplyr)

#============================================================#
#Data ----
#============================================================#

ipca <- gbcbd_get_series(c(433, 4449, 10844, 11428, 27863, 27864), first.date = "01/01/2004")

ipca <- 
  ipca %>%
  mutate(series.name = 
           case_when(id.num == 433 ~ "ipca",
                     id.num == 4449 ~ "administrados",
                     id.num == 10844 ~ "serviços",
                     id.num == 11428 ~ "livres",
                     id.num == 27863 ~ "industriais",
                     id.num == 27864 ~ "alimentos",
                     TRUE ~ series.name))
ipca <- 
  ipca %>%
  select(data = ref.date, valor = value, series.name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "series.name", values_from = "valor")


ipca_tsb <- 
  ipca %>%
  mutate(data = yearmonth(data)) %>%
  arrange(data) %>%
  as_tsibble()



#============================================================#
#fable and future: Time series cross validation forecast ----
#============================================================#
ipca_fable <-
  ipca_tsb %>%
  stretch_tsibble(.step = 1, .init = 144)

model_list <- list()


pdqPDQ <- expand.grid(p = 0:4, d = 0, q = 0:4, P = 0:2, D = 0:1, Q = 0:2)

plan(multisession)

for (i in 1:nrow(pdqPDQ)) {
  
  print(pdqPDQ[i,])
  
  #constante incluída
  model_list[[i]] <-
    ipca_fable %>%
      model(ARIMA(alimentos ~ 1 + pdq(pdqPDQ[i, 1], pdqPDQ[i, 2], pdqPDQ[i, 3]) + 
                    PDQ(pdqPDQ[i, 4], pdqPDQ[i, 5], pdqPDQ[i, 6]))) %>%
      forecast(h = 18) %>%
      group_by(.id) %>%
      mutate(h = row_number()) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      #accuracy requer classe fable
      as_fable(response = "alimentos", distribution = alimentos)
}
```

Comment: What is the generated error description?. I cant' see also the use of futures, you're use simply for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like answer my own question, but it which was too long for a comment. May not be the most elegant solution, but I could solve the error (`Error: object 'pdqPDQ' not found`) using the `listenv` package which allowed me supply the `pdqPDQ` object inside the brackets.

```
model_list <- listenv()

for (i in 1:nrow(pdqPDQ)) {
  
  #constante incluída
  model_list[[i]] %<-% {
    pdqPDQ;
    ipca_fable %>%
      model(ARIMA(alimentos ~ 1 + pdq(pdqPDQ[i, 1], pdqPDQ[i, 2], pdqPDQ[i, 3]) + 
                    PDQ(pdqPDQ[i, 4], pdqPDQ[i, 5], pdqPDQ[i, 6]), method = "ML")) %>%
      rename_with(~c(".id", paste0(pdqPDQ[i,], collapse = ", "))) %>%
      forecast(h = 18) %>%
      group_by(.id) %>%
      mutate(h = row_number()) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      #aparentemente, estruturalmente não muda nada, mas accuracy requer classe fable
      as_fable(response = "alimentos", distribution = alimentos)
  }
```

Comment: There should be no need to add that `pdqPDQ;` line in the first line in the future expression; the future framework picks up `pdqPDQ` as a global variable anyway, because it is found from `pdqPDQ[i, 1]`, `pdqPDQ[i, 2]`, etc.